# Interactive background in a website?

Tags: javascript, background, web

How do i create a website background that has live graphics as in [this](https://apps.evozi.com/) website. The graphics is also interactive to mouse pointers.
*I know it's done through javascript don't know what exactly that technology is called so that I could search about it.*

Answer (score -1):

It use [particles.js](https://vincentgarreau.com/particles.js/), a lightweight JavaScript library for creating particles :)

You can get it [from NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/particles.js).